# What does this と do here?

Tags: syntax, particle-と

I suspect this question to be very simple but nevertheless, I don't understand why と is used here (in particular why not が or の (with the meaning of が)?)

> 交通事情により、表示の時刻**と**前後することがあります。

Comment: The last 出来ます seems highly unnatural to me...as if the sentence were clumsily translated from English. Where is this sentence from?

Comment: 「あります」とか「ございます」でしょうね、普通は。

Comment: This sentence is from a bus stop, I will check if it is really できます or あります like @l'électeur says.

Comment: I checked and yes, it is あります.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This 「と」 indicates the ***standard for comparison*** (and how something can deviate from that standard).

Standard: [表示]{ひょうじ}の[時刻]{じこく} "Times displayed"

Possible deviation: [交通事情]{こうつうじじょう}により[前後]{ぜんご}する "May not arrive/depart on time due to traffic condition"

> 「交通事情により、表示の時刻と前後することがあります。」

In this sentence, the subject for the verb 「前後する」 is unmentioned.  The subject is ***not*** 「表示の時刻」, which is why one cannot use 「表示の時刻**が**」 as you suggest.

The unmentioned subject here is the "***actual arrival/departure times***".  It is saying that those may deviate from the 「表示の時刻」.

The phrase to look for is 「A + が/は + B + **と** + （前後する）」 and in this case, the "A + が/は" part is left unsaid.