# What does と do in the sentence provided below?

Tags: usage

この自動車はあなたの自動車と同じです。(Kono jidōsha wa anata no jidōsha to onajidesu.)

Is it used as "and" ? Or is it comparison like the one provided in [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/34283/what-does-this-%E3%81%A8-do-here).

If yes, then would someone please provide few alternative translations to provide some perspective?

Comment: Think for a moment whether or not "your car AND same" would make sense.  「と」 does not mean "and" nearly as often as Japanese-learners seem to expect.

Comment: @naruto I guessed that much. Is there any alternative?

Comment: I know that. I was formulating sentences with different construction styles and wondered if what I did was correct. Does this work with only two objects in comparison or with multiple items?

Comment: ^Are you asking if you can say AはBとCと同じです to mean "A is the same as B and C"?

Comment: @user3856370 oh yeah. Got it.