# Understanding 生誕と前後して

Tags: grammar

From [this Wikipedia page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%95%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8A%E4%B8%96%E4%BB%A3),

> さとり世代は、**生誕と前後して**バブル崩壊し、不況下の日本しか知らない。

I am uncertain how to understand 生誕と前後して. DeepL tells me that it means "since birth." Then it means something like "around birth"? What と means?

Comment: Related: [What does this と do here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34283/43676)